# How to put Legends into Worksheet Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to legends OR Cards in worksheet chart same in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put the worksheet on a dashboard and change the legend to floating

Comment: why? worksheets are for building visualizations, dashboards focus on presentations and have more options/features for format control. A one worksheet dashboard is common just to do things like this. So if you want to float the legend, you'll need to place it on a dashboard.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Different user here. I have dozens of worksheets, so I'd save a lot of time if I could just making legends float in worksheets. Is this possible? If not, I'll have to deal.

Comment: Nope, dashboards support floating components, not worksheets. At least as of version 10.4. You can always suggest a feature on Tableau's idea forums.